# HTML5 panoramic

Tags: flash, html, panoramas, virtual-reality

I am using this Flash panoramic viewer (http://flashpanoramas.com/player/). But for devices without Flash support are there any good HTML alternatives? It needs to support proper 3d panoramics such as Google Street View.

Answer (score 2):

This is not impossible. I've not tried it yet, but this one works in Flash and HTML5 (only Safari/iPad/iPhone for now, Chrome soon)

http://krpano.com/

Answer (score 1):

Krpano is the resolution to all your problems, is use this with panotour pro to render tours in html5+flash, see website http://www.shoptours.co.uk, there is an example here.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to use the word **impossible** but I think in this case it might apply. At the very least it sounds like the end result would be too horrible to imagine ever being practical.

The only method around it I can think of is creating a video with every single angle in, and using the mouse's drag to skip to certain frames. That would work but you'd need a hell of a lot of frames to make it a smooth transition.

If you go this way, I suggest you limit the scope of movement to just left and right. At least to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Basically [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) is what you need. But it's currently turned off by default in all browser that implement it.